# How to count number of rows in a powershell variable

Tags: powershell

I have the following powershell query :

```
$sql = "select name, lastName, City, Address from Persons"

$TotalPeople = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ResultsInstance -Database $ResultsDatabase -Query $sql

Write-Output "Total number of people run is $TotalPeople  "
```

I want to be able to count the number of rows in the $TotalPeople variable. Is there a way to do this in powershell?

Comment: $TotalPeople.count ?  :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Invoke-sqlCmd returns an array.

You can therefore simply use the `Count` property.

```
$sql = "select name, lastName, City, Address from Persons"
$TotalPeople = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ResultsInstance -Database $ResultsDatabase -Query $sql
Write-Output "Total number of people run is $($TotalPeople.count)"
```